# How to align multiline equations?

Tags: equations, alignment

I am working with equations that are should be broken to multiple lines. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
     O_{max} = w_1 \Sigma_{a=1}^{m} \Sigma_{b=a+1}^{n} (-\left|CPT_a 
     - CPT_b\right|)\\ 
     & + w_2 \Sigma_{j=1}^{m} (DIF_j) + w_3 \Sigma_{j=1}^{m} 
    (INT_j/\Sigma_{x=1}^{n} x_{ij})
\end{aligned}
\label{equ:ho}
\end{equation}
```

and the other one is

```
 \begin{align} 
    \begin{split}
     nr(G_i,r) = 
     \begin{cases}
         1 &  \text{r is naturally played by one member of $G_i$}\\
         -2 &  \text{r is not naturally played in $G_i$} \\
         -p & \text{r is naturally played by p members in $G_i$}\\
     \end{cases}
   \end{split} \nonumber \\ 
   \begin{split}
      nb(G_i) = \Sigma_{r=1}^{9} nr(G_i,r)\\ 
      & max_{\forall G\in C} \left( b(G) = 
      \frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{g}nb(G_i)}{g}\right)
   \end{split}
   \label{equ:yannibelli}       
 \end{align}
```

Alignment of each equation is not the same (second part goes to the right and out of the margin of the pages). How can I fix them, please??

Comment: Should be `i=1` in the last sum?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you post a minimal working example, instead of code snippets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT: 2020/01/01 for the comment of the user @Mico**.
The first alignment with the important suggestion of the user **@Sigur** is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
     O_{\max}& = w_1 \sum_{a=1}^{m} \sum_{b=a+1}^{n} (-\lvert\text{CPT}_a 
         -\text{CPT}_b\rvert)\\ 
         &\quad + w_2 \sum_{j=1}^{m} (\text{DIF}_j) + w_3 \sum_{j=1}^{m} 
        (\text{INT}_j/\sum_{x=1}^{n} x_{ij})
    \end{aligned}
    \label{equ:ho}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

For the second code my proposal to align is:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \begin{document}
    \[\begin{aligned} 
         \mathrm{nr}(G_i,r) & = 
         \begin{cases}
             1 &  \text{$r$ is naturally played by one member of $G_i$}\\
             -2 &  \text{$r$ is not naturally played in $G_i$} \\
             -p & \text{$r$ is naturally played by $p$ members in $G_i$}\\
         \end{cases}\\[3pt]
        \mathrm{nb}(G_i) & = \sum_{r=1}^{9} \mathrm{nr}(G_i,r)\\ 
          & = \max_{\forall G\in C} \left( b(G) = \frac{\sum\limits_{r=1}^{9}\mathrm{nb}(G_i)}{g}\right)
          \label{equ:yannibel}
       \end{aligned} 
       \]
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `&{}\quad +` in the second line.

Comment: @Sigur - There's no difference between `&{}\quad` and `&\quad`, i.e., the `{}` empty math atom is superfluous.

Comment: @Sebastiano - In the first row of the first formula, please replace `\left|` and `\right|` with `\lvert` and `\rvert`. Implementing this change makes a big difference for the spacing between the leading `-` (minus) symbol and the first vertical bar: With `-\lvert`, but not with `-\left|`, one gets the spacing appropriate for a unary operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.

Comment: @Mico I give you my best wishes of happy 2020!!! Many thanks.

Comment: @Mico, well observed. Done.

Comment: @Sigur I have upvote your comment. But into the last sum is it a g or 9 to the denominator? I have put a g like the user has done. IMHO is a 9.

Comment: @Sebastiano, well, I don't know. But OP should know what it is. Don't worry. It is a typo.

Answer (score 5):

I'd do like this (using `\sum` instead of `\Sigma`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
O_{\max} &= w_1 \sum_{a=1}^{m} \sum_{b=a+1}^{n} (-|CPT_a - CPT_b|) \\
&\quad + w_2 \sum_{j=1}^{m} DIF_j + w_3 \sum_{j=1}^{m}  \Bigl(INT_j/\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{ij}\Bigr)
\end{aligned}
\label{equ:ho}
\end{equation}

or another version with \verb|\mathrm{}|:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
O_{\max} &= w_1 \sum_{a=1}^{m} \sum_{b=a+1}^{n} (-|\mathrm{CPT}_a - \mathrm{CPT}_b|) \\
&\quad + w_2 \sum_{j=1}^{m} \mathrm{DIF}_j + w_3 \sum_{j=1}^{m}  \Bigl(\mathrm{INT}_j/\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{ij}\Bigr)
\end{aligned}
\label{equ:ho}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here, I have used \sum before but the output present a dot not the summation symbol. That is what direct me to use \sigma! If you know what is the problem, please let me know.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Alignments *require* the use of alignment symbols - `&` - to properly indicate the horizontal position within successive lines that will be used for alignment purposes. You don't have any of them in the first construction. Here's how it should look:

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
     O_{\max} &= w_1 \sum_{a = 1}^m \sum_{b = a + 1}^n (-\lvert CPT_a 
      - CPT_b \rvert) \\ 
     &\phantom{{}={}} + w_2 \sum_{j = 1}^m (DIF_j) + w_3 \sum_{j = 1}^m 
      (INT_j / \sum_{x = 1}^n x_{ij})
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Note the use of `\max` and `\sum` instead of `max` and `\Sigma`. You may also consider defining `\CPT` and `\DIF` as math operators.

Then, for the second construction, there seems to be no need for `split` here. You can use a nested `equation`-`aligned` just like in the first:

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    nr(G_i, r) &=
      \begin{cases}
         1 & \text{$r$ is naturally played by one member of $G_i$}\\
        -2 & \text{$r$ is not naturally played in $G_i$} \\
        -p & \text{$r$ is naturally played by $p$ members in $G_i$}\\
      \end{cases} \\
    nb(G_i) &= \sum_{r = 1}^9 nr(G_i, r) \\
      & \max_{\forall G \in C} \left( b(G) = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^g nb(G_i)}{g} \right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

It really depends on how you want the alignment to occur, together with the numbering. My assumption here is based on a single numbering for each construction.

Comment: Please do not get mad at me but the output makes only limited sense. At least use `$r$ is naturally played by $p$ members in $G_i$`, i.e. wrap `p` in `$` signs, and do something with the `\max_{\forall G \in C}` (add an equality before or whatever, and drop the `\forall`). I personally would also add punctuations and so on.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Ahhh, forgot about the `p`. I'm not sure what the intent of the `\max` equation is in the OP's request, so I'll leave that as-is.